# I am getting Unknown credential cache type while opening default credentials cache error when using kadmin.local command

Tags: kerberos

I am getting the following error when using kerberos

kadmin.local: Unknown credential cache type while opening default credentials cache

This is version 1.15.4 running on CentOS.

I get this error when using kadmin.local or kinit.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: You need to be logged onto to the CentOS machine as a Kerberos realm user in order for this command to work correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  I was able to solve the problem by commenting out the following line in the /etc/krb5.conf file default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}                          
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Great!  Please make your comment into an answer and self-mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by commenting out the following line in the /etc/krb5.conf file default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}